# Why does it say undefined right before the solution?

Tags: javascript

This gives me the right solution but it says undefined before it - undefinedyoeJ. Can someone lead me in the right direction to what I'm doing wrong? I thank you so very much!!

```js
function reverseWords(str) {
  let strCount = str.length - 1;
  let reverse;
  for (let i = strCount; i >= 0; i--) {
    reverse += str[i];
  }
  return reverse;
}

let finalWord = reverseWords('Joey');
console.log(finalWord);
```

Comment: Not sure if this was an academic exercise, but you could achieve the same with the following JavaScript: `Array.from('Joey').reverse().join('')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reverse is not initialised, so it starts off as "undefined" then the letters are added to it, resulting in "undefinedyeoJ".

make sure to initialise reverse first:

```
let reverse = "";
```

Comment: Thank  you so very much!!

Answer (score 6):

Because `reverse` is initially undefined as it was not initialized. Initialize it as a empty string

```js
function reverseWords(str) {
  let strCount = str.length - 1;
  let reverse = '';
  for (let i = strCount; i >= 0; i--) {
    reverse += str[i];
  }
  return reverse;
}

let finalWord = reverseWords('Joey');
console.log(finalWord);
```

Comment: Ohhhhhh, I see!!! Thank you so very much for your help. I greatly appreciate it.